# Android Canary leak - Billing and ViewBinding

Tags: android, memory-leaks, leakcanary

I imported LeakCanary into my project to understand which and how many memory leaks I had inside, to then be able to fix them. I noticed these two that I can't fix. To put it better, I don't know how to act in code to solve them. Would anyone know how to give me some advice about it?

```
LeakCanary: 2 APPLICATION LEAKS
LeakCanary: References underlined with "~~~" are likely causes.
LeakCanary: Learn more at https://squ.re/leaks.
LeakCanary: 16523886 bytes retained by leaking objects
LeakCanary: Signature: 4594f3337285a2a3dd854a7bf9c944f5598ae18b
LeakCanary: ┬───
LeakCanary: │ GC Root: Global variable in native code
LeakCanary: │
LeakCanary: ├─ android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$DeathMonitor instance
LeakCanary: │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
LeakCanary: │    Retaining 144 bytes in 4 objects
LeakCanary: │    ↓ LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$DeathMonitor.this$0
LeakCanary: │                                               ~~~~~~
LeakCanary: ├─ android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher instance
LeakCanary: │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
LeakCanary: │    Retaining 622 bytes in 8 objects
LeakCanary: │    mContext instance of com.example.packagename.ApplicationContext
LeakCanary: │    ↓ LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.mConnection
LeakCanary: │                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~
LeakCanary: ├─ com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClientImpl$zza instance
LeakCanary: │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
LeakCanary: │    Retaining 41 bytes in 3 objects
LeakCanary: │    ↓ BillingClientImpl$zza.zzd
LeakCanary: │                            ~~~
LeakCanary: ├─ com.example.packagename.fragments.ShopFragment$setupBillingClient$1 instance
LeakCanary: │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
LeakCanary: │    Retaining 12 bytes in 1 objects
LeakCanary: │    Anonymous class implementing com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClientStateListener
LeakCanary: │    ↓ ShopFragment$setupBillingClient$1.this$0
LeakCanary: │                                        ~~~~~~
LeakCanary: ╰→ com.example.packagename.fragments.ShopFragment instance
LeakCanary: ​     Leaking: YES (ObjectWatcher was watching this because com.example.packagename.fragments.ShopFragment received
LeakCanary: ​     Fragment#onDestroy() callback and Fragment#mFragmentManager is null)
LeakCanary: ​     Retaining 16523886 bytes in 33489 objects
LeakCanary: ​     key = b2ebfeff-4177-4587-b7f5-e4c89bc4afaa
LeakCanary: ​     watchDurationMillis = 40425
LeakCanary: ​     retainedDurationMillis = 35424
LeakCanary: 2804 bytes retained by leaking objects
LeakCanary: Signature: 71c80305d50d16354a6bec910e7f529c72e4296
LeakCanary: ┬───
LeakCanary: │ GC Root: Local variable in native code
LeakCanary: │
LeakCanary: ├─ android.os.HandlerThread instance
LeakCanary: │    Leaking: NO (PathClassLoader↓ is not leaking)
LeakCanary: │    Thread name: 'queued-work-looper'
LeakCanary: │    ↓ HandlerThread.contextClassLoader
LeakCanary: ├─ dalvik.system.PathClassLoader instance
LeakCanary: │    Leaking: NO (ViewDataBinding↓ is not leaking and A ClassLoader is never leaking)
LeakCanary: │    ↓ PathClassLoader.runtimeInternalObjects
LeakCanary: ├─ java.lang.Object[] array
LeakCanary: │    Leaking: NO (ViewDataBinding↓ is not leaking)
LeakCanary: │    ↓ Object[].[881]
LeakCanary: ├─ androidx.databinding.ViewDataBinding class
LeakCanary: │    Leaking: NO (a class is never leaking)
LeakCanary: │    ↓ static ViewDataBinding.sReferenceQueue
LeakCanary: │                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
LeakCanary: ├─ java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue instance
LeakCanary: │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
LeakCanary: │    Retaining 724 bytes in 30 objects
LeakCanary: │    ↓ ReferenceQueue.head
LeakCanary: │                     ~~~~
LeakCanary: ├─ androidx.databinding.ViewDataBinding$WeakListener instance
LeakCanary: │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
LeakCanary: │    Retaining 52 bytes in 2 objects
LeakCanary: │    ↓ ViewDataBinding$WeakListener.mObservable
LeakCanary: │                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~
LeakCanary: ├─ androidx.databinding.ViewDataBinding$LiveDataListener instance
LeakCanary: │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
LeakCanary: │    Retaining 16 bytes in 1 objects
LeakCanary: │    ↓ ViewDataBinding$LiveDataListener.mLifecycleOwner
LeakCanary: │                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
LeakCanary: ╰→ com.example.packagename.fragments.InventoryFragment instance
LeakCanary: ​     Leaking: YES (ObjectWatcher was watching this because com.example.packagename.fragments.InventoryFragment
LeakCanary: ​     received Fragment#onDestroy() callback and Fragment#mFragmentManager is null)
```

As you can see, there are mainly 2 leaks but I'm not sure I know how to fix them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first leaktrace shows that `ShopFragment` sets up a `BillingClientStateListener` in `ShopFragment$setupBillingClient`, probably by calling `BillingClient#startConnection()`. The `BillingClientStateListener` implementation in an anonymous class and has a reference to an instance of its outer class, `ShopFragment`. Looking at the [Javadoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient#endconnection), it seems that you need to call `BillingClient#endConnection()` once you're done, i.e. when the fragment is destroyed. The billing [documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate) does not mention this at all so you might want to file a documentation bug.

The second leaktrace shows that the `ViewDataBinding.LiveDataListener` associated with the destroyed InventoryFragment is held in memory by `ViewDataBinding.sReferenceQueue` (see the [sources here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/data-binding/+/refs/heads/mirror-goog-studio-master-dev/extensions/library/src/main/java/androidx/databinding/ViewDataBinding.java). The fact that `ViewDataBinding$WeakListener` is in the queue means that `ViewDataBinding.WeakListener` is not strongly reachable. `ViewDataBinding. processReferenceQueue()` is in charge of doing that, so it looks like it hasn't been called in a while. It's hard to say for sure without a heap dump, but this looks like a DataBinding library bug and you should file a ticket.

Comment: Here's a video of the investigation leading to this answer: https://www.loom.com/share/3c9c4e8ae6e74a41b09258517c5c80ed

Comment: You've been more than clear about both leaks. Thank you very much :-)